# matrix.translate vs matrix.translate3d webkit ipad

Tags: ipad, animation, webkit, transform

The following code is part of a webkit transition for an Ipad app:

```
#canvas {
        -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        position:absolute;  
        z-index:1;  
    }
```

...

```
var containerTrsfrm = window.getComputedStyle(currentCanvas).webkitTransform;
    var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(containerTrsfrm);
    matrix = matrix.scale(1.5, 1.5);
    currentCanvas.style.webkitTransform = matrix.translate(100, 100);
```

But if I change `matrix.translate(x,y)` to `matrix.translate3d(x,y,z)` it stops working. Now, I wanna make this change because I read in several places that this will be supported by hardware acceleration and the flickering that occurs when executing the code above, will go away.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This fixed my flicker issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8348758/886893

Answer (score 1):

I just spent a few hours on this flicker problem at the end of animations in webkit transforms / ipad /iOS / webWiew.

What I found is that the object being transformed is placed on top of the other objects in the window during the transform and at the end of the transform, all objects that have a higher z-index are redrawn, wich causes the flickering.

So just give the transformed div a higher z-index than the other objects and the flicker disappears.

Jet

Answer (score 0):

In javascript 2d and 3d use the same methods.
If you want to do a 3d transform you just have to use matrix.translate(x,y,z).
But if you don't use the z value, there is no point using translate this way.

Like you said, the css translate3d is hardware accelerated. But I don't really know about matrix vs matrix3d.

When applied to the style (currentCanvas.style.webkitTransform) javascript choose if it should return a 2d or 3d matrix depending of the value. To really force it, you can still add a 1 pixel translation on the z axis.